# Shortcut for fast recursive removal

Tags: command-line, files

Sometimes I want to delete large swaths of temporary files recursively, and recycle the directory name without waiting for the command to complete. (For example, if I want to nuke and re-checkout a version control working copy.)

While this doesn't happen all that often, when it does I usually use a command like:

```
mv "$oldname" dienow && rm -rf dienow &
```

I could create a function or alias for this, of course, but without doing that is there a shorter way to express the above?

Comment: That's pretty short already.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking for? As you've written your example, it looks equivalent to `rm -rf "$oldname" &`. I assume that doesn't do what you want, so a better example would be helpful.

Comment: @WarrenYoung it is equivalent, but frees up the name "$oldname" so I can use it without waiting for all its contents to be unlinked first.

Comment: In that case, then I'd say a function or alias *is* the way to make it shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would stick with two separate commands:

```
mv "$oldname" dienow
rm -rf dienow
```

This way, if you accidentally recall a line from your history, you don't risk causing major damage by running a single command. The `mv` command doesn't delete `"$oldname"` even if it's the new version, and the `rm` command only deletes something that you've already declared as to-be-deleted.

If you feel lucky and insist on a single command, make it a function:

```
mv_then_rm () {
  mv -- "$1" "$1.TO_BE_DELETED" && rm -rf -- "$1.TO_BE_DELETED" &
}
```

Here's a multi-parameter version that ensures the “to be deleted” directory doesn't exist yet.

```
mv_then_rm () {
  local d tmpdir tmpdirs
  tmpdirs=()
  for d; do
    tmpdir=$(mktemp -- "$(dirname -- "$d")/.deleting.XXXXXXXXXX")
    tmpdirs+=$tmpdir
    mv -- "$d" "$tmpdir"
  done
  rm -rf -- "$tmpdirs" &
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the recreation of "$oldname".

```
mv "$oldname" dienow && mkdir "$oldname" && \rm -rf dienow &
```

I prefer to use \rm just in case someone's aliased rm to something like rm -i

Make your paths explicit and add as function to profile

```
clean_old_now(){
  \mv "$oldname" dienow && mkdir "$oldname" && \rm -rf dienow &
}
```

If you're worried about doing this accidentally add a prompt

```
clean_old_now(){
  read -p "Are you sure?: " sure
  if [[ $? = 0 ]] && [[ "$sure" = "y" ]]; then
    \mv "$workdir/$oldname" $workdir/dienow && mkdir "$workdir/$oldname" && \rm -rf $workdir/dienow &
  fi
}
```

When adding explicit paths make sure the mv stays in the same filesystem to prevent the data being copied

Comment: Good idea on the prompt; however, I have to point out that (in `clean_old_now`) it's not a good idea to use the `[` command without quoting variables, and the `==` makes it unportable without gaining anything. I gather this is bash, so if you want to edit it to use the `[[` keyword or quote the vars and get rid of the extra equals sign, I can +1 it.

Comment: done. One may embellish as much as wanted.
$sure could be made local, tests for $workdir $oldname being set, etc. just trying to stick with brevity for now. Personally I'd add -v switches to mv and mkdir

Comment: I changed || to &&, surprised no one caught that, self included

Answer (score 0):

A **very** pragmatic approach would be to move the directory to /tmp and let the reboot of the machine do the rest. Or establish a cronjob that cleans up periodically (once an hour).

```
mv "$oldname" /tmp/forgetme
```

And as cronjob

```
0 * * * * rm -rf /tmp/forgetme
```

Comment: This assumes `/tmp` is on the same filesystem as "$oldname". If that's not the case, it would be very slow.

Comment: True! You are right, I did not think about that.